# R manuals are not opening in offline mode in linux mint 17.1

Tags: linux, r

I've been using R for a long time, but I'm facing an error that I've never seen before. Manuals are supplied with R installation and I'm using Linux Mint 17.1 with R installed (v 3.2.0).

Whenever I issue `help.start()`, it opens my browser with this url:

> http://127.0.0.1:29013/doc/html/index.html.

But if I click on any manuals e.g. "An Introduction to R", the browser redirects to

> http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-intro.html

Which means ther'is something wrong that prevents offline manuals being displayed or it may be that offline manuals are not present in my system. But the documentation regarding function is still working offline.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this may be a Mint packaging problem. I compiled and installed R, and the documentation is installed like this:

```
<path>
    html
        here are some jpgs and htmls - and the index.html
    manual
        R-FAQ.htm, R-admin.html, etc...
```

So, if your entrance point is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:29013/doc/html/index.html
```

then the actual manuals should be in

```
http://127.0.0.1:29013/doc/manual
```

I suggest you have a look at the `index.html` page and check the links there.

Also, in my case, the documentation was installed under `/usr/lib64/R/doc`. Does this doc exist in your installation? (`/usr/lib64` might be `/usr/lib` in your case)

Comment: No I don't have the **doc** directory under `/usr/lib`. But I have installed R using backport

Comment: I've uploaded a tar.gz of the file [here](http://expirebox.com/files/3bd57ff874a25a697b93d09569f10d8d.gz). I would suggest you put a message on the Linux Mint forums though, so the problem gets resolved if any.

Comment: Now my problem is solved. I have installed `r-doc-html`, `r-doc-pdf` from linux mint software manager. Now I can access html help files within RStudio. These are the extra things that I have to do.